# Automapper - Map array of objects to one single object

Tags: c#-4.0, mapping, automapper

I would like map array of objects to one single object.

For example:

```
public class ArrayData
{
  //name of property in class MyObject in upper under score casing
  public string PropName{get;set;}

  //value of property in class MyObject
  public string PropValue{get;set;}
}
```

Source data:

```
ArrayData [] sourceData = new ArrayData[]{new ArrayData{PropName="MY_ID",PropValue="1"}}
```

Destination object:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public int MyId{get;set;}
}
```

**My aim is set MyObject.MyId to 1.**

Convention is:

```
if(ArrayData.PropName == MyObject.Property.Name)
{
   MyObject.PropName = ArrayData.PropValue;
}
```

**EDITED: I tried this way:**

```
public class UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention : INamingConvention
{
    #region Implementation of INamingConvention

    public Regex SplittingExpression
    {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string SeparatorCharacter
    {
        get { return string.Format("_"); }
    }

    #endregion
}

public class TestProfile: Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName { get { return "TestProfile"; } }
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();

        CreateMap<ArrayData, MyObject>()
                           .ForMember(dest => dest.MyId, opt =>
                                            {
                                                opt.Condition(src => src.ColumnName == "MY_ID");
                                                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value);
                                            });
    } 
}
```

Conversion:

```
        Mapper.Initialize((obj) => obj.AddProfile(new TestProfile()));

        var myClass = Mapper.Map<ArrayData[], MyClass>(sourceData);
```

It doesnt work, I get this exception:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.

Also I think it is not good solution map all properties manualy:

```
 .ForMember(dest => dest.MyId, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.ColumnName =="MY_ID"))
```